# Augmented Images consists of empty arrays whereas Original images consists of arrays with values. Why is it so?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I change the extensions of all .png images to .jpeg inside a folder and also renamed them into using this code,

```
# Define directories

INPUT = 'input dir'
OUTPUT = 'output dir'

for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(INPUT)):
    dst = "OTHERS_IMG_" + str(count) + ".jpeg"
    src = INPUT + filename 
    dst = OUTPUT + dst 
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

I successfully got images in right format like this inside a separate folder like this.
NORMAL_IMG_0
NORMAL_IMG_1
NORMAL_IMG_2
.
.
.

But after augmenting and reading the images using OpenCV  and imgaug I got empty arrays like this using this code,

```
image = cv2.imread('NORMAL/NORMAL_IMG_0.jpeg')
rotate = iaa.Affine(rotate=(-25, 25))
image_rotated = rotate.augment_images([image])[0]
cv2.imwrite("image.jpeg", image_rotated)
```

I got this,

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ...

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

While the original image is like this,

```
[[[ 55  33  21]
  [ 47  25  13]
  [ 52  30  18]
  ...
  [ 27  18  28]
  [ 29  20  30]
  [ 29  21  28]]

 [[ 81  58  43]
  [ 77  54  39]
  [ 82  59  44]
  ...
  [ 25  18  25]
  [ 26  19  26]
  [ 26  19  26]]

 [[100  74  57]
  [100  74  57]
  [101  75  58]
  ...
  [ 24  18  23]
  [ 24  18  23]
  [ 24  18  23]]

 ...

 [[ 32  29  31]
  [ 30  25  27]
  [ 31  25  26]
  ...
  [ 61  37  31]
  [ 61  37  31]
  [ 61  37  31]]

 [[ 30  27  29]
  [ 29  26  28]
  [ 30  25  27]
  ...
  [ 49  28  26]
  [ 48  27  25]
  [ 48  27  25]]

 [[ 28  27  29]
  [ 29  26  28]
  [ 28  25  27]
  ...
  [ 40  22  21]
  [ 39  21  20]
  [ 39  21  20]]]
```

Can anyone help me why this is happening? I also want to augment all my images. I didn't notice this until I tried to augment my images which are in **JPEG** format inside a directory.

Comment: Why are you giving PNG files a “.jpeg” extension? You do know that changing the extension doesn’t change the format of the image stored in the file, right? It will just confuse the image reader to try to interpret the PNG data stream as a JPEG data stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the extensions, try writing them as the jpeg format with a jpeg extension. JPEG is not PNG. You can use `cv2.imread` followed by `cv2.imwrite`, or imagemagick's convert utility. Then try again.